# how to set RememberMe CodeIgniter Spark

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to set the  joeauty / RememberMe-CodeIgniter-Spark. I added the rememberme.php inside the config forler, the Rememberme.php inside system/libraries/  made the changes inside autoload.php and config.php and created 2 tables( ci_cookies and  ci_sessions) into the database.
If don't click the checkbox I can login, but if I select the checkbox nothing happens.

This is my controller:

```
function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('registerclient_model','',TRUE);
 }

  function index()
  {

    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') || $this->session->userdata('user_id'))
      { redirect('client_private_area', 'refresh');}

    else{

      $this->load->library('form_validation');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

      if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
      {
        $data['error'] = 'Invalid email address and/or password.';
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/login/client_login', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
      }
      else
      {
        //Go to private area
        redirect('client_private_area', 'refresh');
      }
    }

  }

function check_database($password)
  {
    $email = $this->input->post('email_address');
    $result = $this->registerclient_model->login($email, $password);

    if($result){

      if($this->input->post('netid') == "on"){

        $this->rememberme->setCookie($this->input->post('netid'));

        if ($this->rememberme->verifyCookie()) {
            // find user id of cookie_user stored in application database
            $user = User::findUser($cookie_user);
            // set session if necessary
            if (!$this->session->userdata('user_id')) {
                $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user);
            }
            $this->user = $user;
        }
        else if ($this->session->userdata('user_id')) {
            $this->user = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        }
      } 
      else
      {
        $sess_array = array();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
          $sess_array = array(
            'id' => $row->id,
            'first_name' => $row->first_name,
            'email_address' => $row->email_address
          );
          $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
        }
        return TRUE;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid email address and/or password.');
      return false;
    }
  }
```

this is my model:

```
function login($email, $password) {
    //create query to connect user login database
    $this->db->select('id, first_name, email_address, password');
    $this->db->from('client_register');
    $this->db->where('email_address', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $this->registerclient_model->hash($password));
    $this->db->limit(1);

    //get query and processing
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() == 1) 
    {
      return $query->result(); //if data is true
    } 
    else 
    {
      return false; //if data is wrong
    }
  }
```

this is my view:

```
<div class="client_login_content_form"> 
    <h1>CLIENT LOGIN FORM</h1>
      <p class="loginform_error"><?php echo validation_errors(''); ?></p>
      <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
        <ul>
          <li><input type="text" size="20" id="email" name="email_address" value="<?php echo set_value('email_address'); ?>" required placeholder="Email Address"/></li>
          <li><input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>"  required placeholder="Password"/></li>
          <li><p><input type="checkbox" name="netid" id="netid" checked>Remember me</p></li>
          <li><input type="submit" class="login_content_form_button" value="LOG IN"/></li>
        </ul>
        <p class="forgot_login"><a href="<?php echo site_url('verifylogin/forgot'); ?>">Forgot your password?</a></p>
      </form>
  </div>
  <form action="<?php echo site_url('admin'); ?>"><input type="submit" value="Admin" class="admin_button" /></form>
```

Comment: You don't install sparks into your `/application` folder, they go in the `sparks` folder.  See: http://getsparks.org/install and http://getsparks.org/get-sparks

Comment: This may help too: http://getsparks.org/packages/RememberMe/versions/HEAD/show

Comment: so for using RememberMe I have to install the Spark Manager folder in my project?

Comment: Yes.  `RememberMe` is a spark, so it needs to be installed as one.